# Change the redirect destination by which plugin was used in yesod-auth

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm using multiple plugins(Yesod.Auth.Email, Yesod.Auth.OAuth2.Github, etc).
I want to change the redirect destination by which plugin was used.

I want to do something like following:

```
instance YesodAuth App where
    loginDest _ =
        | plugin == "email" = HomeR
        | plugin == "github" = SettingR
```

How can I do?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can be done directly like this. However you could have the login destination be a page that checks for a session value telling you which plugin was used for login and redirect from there.

Comment: Thank you. Using session is good way!
And, I noticed by this answer.
This way seems can be easily implemented by setting `redirectToRefere` and using `setUltDest` in `authenticate`.